# Lindemann-HInshelwood mechanism difference between high and low concentration

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics, rate-equation

I have a gas reaction which follows the Lindemann-Hinshelwood mechanism and want to calculate the rate constant at low and at high concentrations of the gas but I find myself stuck at what my next step should be and hope someone here could push me in the right direction.

I have that the effective rate constants are $1.01×10^{−5}$ s$^{−1}$  at a concentration of $4.6×10^{−6}$ M and $2.21×10^{−5}$ s$^{−1}$ at a concentration of $8.71×10^{−5}$ M (which are relative low concentrations). Hence, I get that the effective rate constant can be written as:

$$k_\mathrm{eff} = \frac{k_\mathrm{a}k_\mathrm{b}[\ce{A}]}{k_\mathrm{b} + k^{'}_\mathrm{a}[\ce{A}]}\tag{1}$$

and since $k_b$ >> $k^{'}_a [A]$, which then gives:

$$k_\mathrm{eff} = \frac{k_\mathrm{a}k_\mathrm{b}[\ce{A}]}{k_\mathrm{b}} ={k_\mathrm{a}[\ce{A}]}\tag{2}$$

So

$$k_a = \frac{k_{eff}}{[A]}=\frac{k_{eff,2}-k_{eff,1}}{[A]_2 - [A]_1} = \frac{2.21×10^{−5}-1.01×10^{−5}}{8.71×10^{−5} - 4.6×10^{−6}} = 0.145 M^{-1} s^{-1}$$

**HOWEVER** from what I have seen online it should be that

$$\frac{1}{k_{eff}} =\frac{1}{k_a [A]}$$

So

$$k_a =\frac{1/k_{eff,2} - 1/k_{eff,1}}{1/[A]_2 - 1/[A]_1} = 3.83 M^{-1}s^{-1}$$

Which I don't think this is correct, but that is the only way that I have seen it been calculated. But why does it go from being $k_{eff}$ to being $\frac{1}{k_{eff}}$? Or is my way of doing it correct?

Further, if I then want to calculate the rate constant at **high** concentration of the gas, $k_a [A]>>k_b$, then  eq. (1) can be rewritten as:

$$k_\mathrm{eff} = \frac{k_\mathrm{a}k_\mathrm{b}}{k^{'}_\mathrm{a}}\tag{3}$$

But since I don't have $k_b$ or $k_{a}^{'}$ how can I calculate $k_a$ at $298$ K?

I truly hope someone can help me with this, I have tried to find similar problems online but I can only find one and I don't understand why the expression for $k_{eff}$ is as it is. I also can't find anything regarding calculation for high concentrations without being given the other rate constants. Thank you!

Comment: Without reading everything, aren't your equation (2) and the equation which comes after "however" exactly equivalent? (Provided everything is non-zero, of course).

Comment: @LinearChristmas I thought so too but when calculating $k_a$ with eq. (2) and the equation after "however" I get two different answers. From eq. (2) I get that $k_a = 0.145$ and from the other eq. I get $k_a = 3.83$.

Comment: If agree that the equations are equivalent, then any forms for $k_a$ derived from them must also be equivalent. Why do you then use a different equation for $k_a$ after "So" than you did before?

Comment: Your eqn 2 cannot apply as $k_a$ has only one value and the ratio of $k_{eff}/[A]$ is different for your data. Try taking the reciprocal of eqn 1 and plot $1/k_{eff}$ vs $1/[A]$ to get the gradient $k_a$ (or do so algebraically) and also the intercept. This gives the answer $k_a=3.83$ so this seems to be what you have done here.